# How to get the name of a form from formbuider?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ive got a form:

```
<%= form_for('FormName',:url => "some/action") do |fv| %>
  fv.text_field :field_name
<% end %>
```

Is it possible knowing only fv to get the form name ("FormName") inside a form codeblock ?

Comment: `fv.object`  gives you the object used in `form_for`

Comment: Your answer lies in the `form_for` itself.For example `<%= form_for @post do |f| %>`,here it refers to the `post` record's `form`

Comment: actually I don't pass a model to form_for but just a string 'FormName'. So fv.object.class.name returns a "NilClass" string. I know that I can just hardcode that string again, but Im looking for a smarter way

Comment: @lx00st In your case i think you want `fv.object_name` if i am not wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fv.object` gives you the object used in form helper.

If you want the Model name as a String, you can do

```
fv.object.class.name
```

**EDIT**

For this case, you can call

```
fv.object_name
```

Comment: actually I don't pass a model to form_for but just a string 'FormName'. So fv.object.class.name returns a "NilClass" string. I know that I can just hardcode that string again, but Im looking for a smarter way.